# Don't display class name in Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xunit, test-explorer

I am using Xunit in my vs project. In my Test explorer, I see this:

```
Fully.Qualified.Namespace.ClassName.TestName1
Fully.Qualified.Namespace.ClassName.TestName2
etc.
```

I would much rather just see this:

```
TestName1
TestName2
etc.
```

or even this (2nd best, but still a big improvement):

```
ClassName.TestName1
ClassName.TestName2
etc.
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

add a file to the root directory of your test project named `xunit.runner.json`
with the following content:

```
{
  "methodDisplay": "method"
}
```